# How to calculate static air temperature

Tags: acoustics, ideal-gas, speed

Let's suppose I have an airplane flying at an unpecified altitude and the following data are given:

1. Flight Mach number: $M=0.76M$
2. Ground speed: $V_{kts}=470kts$

My goal is to estimate the air static temperature $T{s}$. What formula should I use in order to determine such variable?

I tried to use the formula of speed of sound $c=\sqrt{γRT}$ where $γ=1.4$ and  $R=287JkgK$ and I specified $c=v_{ms}$. By substituting the second formula into the first one and inverting it I get

$T=\left(\frac{V_{m/s}}{M}\right)^2\frac{1}{γR}$
Notice: I have converted the speed from knots to meters per second!

Answer (score 1):

Your formula looks almost OK. There should not be a "T" in the denominator on the right side. 
Other than that, what is your question actually?

Comment: I corrected the formula as suggested. No further questions for the moment thanks.